# Does $w^*-X^*$ topology coincide with $w-X^*$ topology, if $X$ is reflexive?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

The properties (for example) of the Clarke's subdifferetnial concerning the value set include endowing $X^*$ with $w^*$-topology, while any proof which deals with the convergance of its values includes just weak convergance in $X^*$. The common thing is, that the Banach space $X$ is reflexive (so its dual) and I started to wondering if these two topologies coincide if $X$ is reflexive? Do you know the proof or a book where I could study it? - naturally if my hypothesis is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because for reflexive spaces the cannonical embedding $i:X\to X^{**}$ is an isometric isomorphism.

Let $\tau_1$ denote the weak-star topology on $X^*$, and $\tau_2$ the weak topology on $X^*$.

The weak topology on $X^*$ is the weakest topology in which every functional $x^{**}\in X^{**}$ is continuous on $X^*$.

The weak-star topology on $X^*$ is the weakest topology in which every functional of the form $i(x)\in X^{**}$ is continuous on $X^*$.

By reflexivity, every $x^{**}\in X^{**}$ is of the form $i(x)$ for some $x\in X$, and so every member of the topology $\tau_1$ is also a member of $\tau_2$, but on the other hand $\tau_2$ is the weakest topology with the property above, so $\tau_1=\tau_2$.

You may find more details, e.g., [here](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6338/summer08/section9e.pdf).